# Using Lights on Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, light

I'm trying to use the light properties. I want to know more about the variable meanig in the [DirectionalLight.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/lights/DirectionalLight.js) and [SpotLight.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/lights/SpotLight.js) source codes.

For example, what is the diference between castShadow and onlyShadow.

How can I control lights to not pass objects? For example, I have a house with walls and I want to control light for each room.

---

I find the PointLight. It is working well. But when I put more than 4 lights, they are not working. Are there some restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs)?

- [DirectionalLight](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/DirectionalLight)
- [SpotLight](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/SpotLight)

Comment: Yes. But I'm still in doubt. Think about a house. We have walls separating the rooms and each ambient has your own light. But when I use only one Diretional light, it is illuminating all the rooms. I want to put different Diretional lights in different places.